# Slide up image on page load

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make the image slide up all fancy like in the middle area underneath the header when the page loads. So here is my jQuery so far:

```
$(function() {
        $("#product_img").on('load', function() {
        $(this).show('slide', {
            direction: 'up' }, 2000); });
});
```

I've also tried this:

```
$("#product_img").animate({'up':200},255,'linear', function() {console.log('Done Animation'); })
```

In which it prints 'Done Animation' in the Chrome debugger.. but it doesn't show the image. :/
The image right now is just #product_img { display: none; } in my CSS. Is there something that I'm missing? D:

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Animate animates css properties that's why `up` isn't working. `show` also doesn't work that way. I'd recommend reading the documentation before going any further: http://api.jquery.com/show/ & http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
$("#product_img").one('load', function () {
    $(this).slideDown(2000);
}).each(function () {
    if (this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');
});
```

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/bbR8Y/2/

Comment: @Peanut - no problem :) I just made a slight update to it so you can either use the one you have or the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#product_img").slideUp(1000, 'linear', function(){});
```

Update. This will hide the image. Try slideDown instead:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/qeTM2/2/
```

Comment: No it didn't work. I don't know if this would help if I gave the link to it:
http://neofill.com/design/checkout/

Comment: Slide up, or down, not sure what you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The image has display:none. What about a setTimeout()?

Comment: @Peanut I see you have a lot of stuff going on before the slideup function. Try putting an alert just before the slideup to make sure everything is working Ok. If that fails try replacing .slideUp with .fadeIn to make sure it is not because the img is hidden.

Comment: I had yours working a little bit, it was doing something weird. It was sliding it up , but then shrunk back down and disappeared.. I dont know what was going on.